# D3 chart from csv http url

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am trying to get a column chart using d3.js. The data source is in csv format from url:`https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/***/feed.csv?key=***&start=2015-11-24%2010:00:00&end=2015-11-24%2014:00:00`so the code is:

```
 // Parse the date / time
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC").parse;


 d3.csv("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/***/feed.csv?key=***&start=2015-11-24%2010:00:00&end=2015-11-24%2014:00:00", function (error, data) {
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.created_at);
            d.value = +d.field1;
        });

        x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
```

The csv http url format data is :

```
created_at,entry_id,field1,field2
2015-11-24 10:09:38 UTC,1032,6,6
2015-11-24 10:39:37 UTC,1033,4,10
```

This is the error i get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullYear' of null
>   from d3.v3.min.js:1,

I have tested with a local csv file with the same data and it works.

I have also enabled CORS and it still not work.

What can be the problem?.
Thank you very much.

Comment: When I go to the url provided, I get a 'the page you were looking for does not exist' error. Do you have the correct url?

Comment: Hello. I am sorry but the URL is only an example of source csv http request data.